P4V says I have the latest revision of a file but I don't
Why would P4V say I have the latest revision of a file when I don't? I used the "p4 diff -sd" and "p4 diff -se" commands to find the files that were causing issues and "force get latest" on them, which resolved the errors. I don't want to keep checking to see if I'm up to date on all the files I need so how do I stop this going forward? Thanks
